# xslt/xquery for checking values of two attributes in if conditions

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, xslt-1.0, xquery

I am stuck at a place in my xquery. In the response i want to get back the phone numbers for each Type i.e. HOME and CELL , but only the ones which have highest sequence number .If there are two rows with PhoneType="HOME" , I want back the phone which has highest sequence of two i.e in my case Sequence="3".

With my xquery I am able to get back a phoneType="HOME" and the first row with type HOME. i am not able to add a condition to check the Sequence as well. Where and how can i add it. Please suggest. Thanks in advance

Part of my Xquery:

```
 <acc:phones>
                 {
                for $PersonPhonesRow in $PersonMaintenanceResponse/ns2:CMPersonService/ns2:CMPersonDetails/ns2:PersonPhones/ns2:PersonPhonesRow[@PhoneType="HOME"][1]
                    return
                    if(fn:data($PersonMaintenanceResponse/ns2:CMPersonService/ns2:CMPersonDetails/ns2:PersonPhones/ns2:PersonPhonesRow/@PhoneType="HOME"[1]))
                    then
                    <com:phone>
                            <com:type>{'HOME'}</com:type>
                            <com:phoneNumber>{fn:data($PersonMaintenanceResponse/ns2:CMPersonService/ns2:CMPersonDetails/ns2:PersonPhones/ns2:PersonPhonesRow[@PhoneType="HOME"][1]/@PhoneNumber)}</com:phoneNumber>
                            <com:carrier>{fn:data($PersonMaintenanceResponse/ns2:CMPersonService/ns2:CMPersonDetails/ns2:PersonPhones/ns2:PersonPhonesRow[@PhoneType="HOME"][1]/@Extension)}</com:carrier>
                    </com:phone>
                    else
                   ()
                  }
                </acc:phones>
```

Request:

```
<CMPerson xmlns="http://splwg.com/CMPerson.xsd">
     <CMPersonService>    
        <CMPersonDetails>
           <PersonPhones>
              <PersonPhonesHeader PersonID="1234567890" LastSequenceNumber="9"/>
              <PersonPhonesRow PersonID="1234567890" Sequence="1" PhoneType="HOME" IntlPrefix="" PhoneNumber="(850) 123-0000" Extension="" Version="12" PhoneAlgorithmParamValue="(999) 999-9999"/>
              <PersonPhonesRow PersonID="1234567890" Sequence="2" PhoneType="CELL" IntlPrefix="" PhoneNumber="(850) 000-0000" Extension="" Version="3" PhoneAlgorithmParamValue="(999) 999-9999"/>
              <PersonPhonesRow PersonID="1234567890" Sequence="3" PhoneType="HOME" IntlPrefix="" PhoneNumber="(850) 123-1111" Extension="ATT" Version="1" PhoneAlgorithmParamValue="(999) 999-9999"/>
              <PersonPhonesRow PersonID="1234567890" Sequence="4" PhoneType="BUSN" IntlPrefix="" PhoneNumber="(904) 111-1111" Extension="" Version="3" PhoneAlgorithmParamValue="(999) 999-9999"/>              
           </PersonPhones>
        </CMPersonDetails>
     </CMPersonService>
  </CMPerson>
```

Response required:

```
<acc:phones>
      <com:phone xmlns:com="******">
        <com:type>HOME</com:type>
        <com:phoneNumber>(850) 123-1111</com:phoneNumber>
        <com:carrier>ATT</com:carrier>
      </com:phone>
       <com:phone xmlns:com="******">
        <com:type>CELL</com:type>
        <com:phoneNumber>(904) 111-1111</com:phoneNumber>
        <com:carrier></com:carrier>
      </com:phone>
    </acc:phones>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query to be used:

```
        let $PersonMaintenanceResponse := 'Your request'
        let $uniqPhoneType    :=distinct-values($PersonMaintenanceResponse/ns2:CMPersonService/ns2:CMPersonDetails/ns2:PersonPhones/ns2:PersonPhonesRow/@PhoneType)
        for $each at $i in $uniqPhoneType
        return 
        <acc:phones>
        {
        let $seq    := $PersonMaintenanceResponse/ns2:CMPersonService/ns2:CMPersonDetails/ns2:PersonPhones/ns2:PersonPhonesRow[(@PhoneType = $each)]
        let $maxValue := max($seq/@Sequence)
        let $maxrow := $seq[@Sequence eq $maxValue]
        return 
        <com:phone xmlns:com="*******">
        <com:type>{$each}</com:type>
        <com:phoneNumber>{$maxrow/@PhoneNumber}</com:phoneNumber>
        <com:carrier>{$maxrow/@Extension}</com:carrier>
        </com:phone>
        }</acc:phones>
```

Comment: Thank u. i will try this one.

Comment: @simran, If answer fulfill your requirement please mark ok